# Angular ng-if directive breaks web component exported with Angular elements

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

I would desperately ask for help to check if this is an Angular issue, an Angular element issue or a issue that I caused.

### Intro

In our client project we're exporting components as web components with the help of Angular elements. With a certain use case I'm facing issues which is stacking a web component inside another web component. Let me go into detail by providing you snippets from the test project that I pushed to github: https://github.com/aetzlecx/angular-elements-stacking/ (The test project is very simplified to just demonstrate the issue and leave out other unnecessary details or project related details)

**Side note**: I tried this with Angular version 10, 11 and 12 ;).

### The parent component

The parent component uses content projection to include child components with the help of `ng-content`. A button simply toggles the child content:

```html
<button (click)="triggerButtonClicked()">Toggle</button>

<p>Child content:</p>
<div *ngIf="childVisible">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  childVisible = true;
  triggerButtonClicked(): void {
    this.childVisible = !this.childVisible;
  }
}
```

Inside of an Angular application when I stack an element into the component it works without any issues and clicking the button makes the child content toggling as expected.

### The child component

However when I also now export other Angular components as web components and stack them under the Parent component then I face difficulties with the following test codes. `wc-child` is just a component that display the given items in an unordered list (`ul` > `li`). However the type of web component doesn't matter (simple ones vs. complex ones).

**1st use case**:

```html
<wc-parent>
  <wc-child items="A,B,C"></wc-child>
</wc-parent>
```

This causes that the web component disappears after the 2nd toggle.

[Demo 1st use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTuXb.gif)

The DOM looks like this:

[DOM 1st use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a53DV.png)

**2nd use case**:
Wrapping the web component within a div:

```html
<wc-parent>
  <div>
    <wc-child items="A,B,C"></wc-child>
  </div>
</wc-parent>
```

This example causes that the content of the web component immediately disappears after the first toggle:

[Demo 1st use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fXiK.gif)

The DOM looks pretty similar as in the first example

### Debugging attempts

Details of my debugging attempts:

- When I try to toggle the component by setting the `display` attribute to either `block` or `none` it works perfectly.
- What I also did so far is to remove `@angular/elements` dependency and copy the elements code into my project and poke around the elements code. I discovered that basically the `NgElement` implemented the whole web component's life cycle process which is on `disconnectedCallback` destroying the component and on `connectedCallback` initializing it again. I can see within the Chrome Dev tools that after the first toggle the component doesn't have the attribute anymore set (e.g. by calling `document.querySelector('wc-child').items` which evaluates then to `undefined`)

Any help here would be very appreciated :)

Many thx
Cheers

Comment: Hi, I've found this question via your reply in the thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38778, and yes, I think the problem is the same. Angular Elements has a quite broken handling of the life cycle of Web Components.

Comment: @MaxArt thank you for confirming the issue. that helps a lot